# Sequelize method providing undefined

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new for sequelize and express js.

I need to get data from mysql. I have created table and data via sync method.

```
function getUserData() {
    user.findAll().then(users => {
        return users
    })
}

console.log(getUserData());
```

This is for getting user data. If i access this function, I am getting undefined error. I don't know why it's happened.

Please anyone help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findAll().` returns the `promise` , so you can access the data like this :

```
function getUserData() {
    return user.findAll().then(users => { // <--- Need to add `return` 
        return users
    }); // <---- Will return promise
}

getUserData().then(data => { console.log(data); }); // <--- So you can access the data this way
```

Comment: Thanks Vivek. I am getting this error "TypeError: getUserData.then is not a function"

Comment: its `getUserData().then` not `getUserData.then`

Comment: I have only 11 reputations. minimum 15 reputations required for putting upvote.